# PyVista ray_trace

Tags: python, arrays, raytracing, pyvista

I am working on an FoV app. The goal is simple - you have a vehicle with a mounted sensor with specific FoV formed with individual rays. In front of the vehicle, I placed a couple of obstacles, which should adjust the lenght of each ray colliding with the obstacle. Also, when I rotate the FoV by some margin, I need the rays to be adjusted by the vehicle's mesh - your car can also be an obstacle.

I have managed to accomplish both of these conditions (condition 1 - ray lenght is adjusted by the obstacle, but not by the vehicle itself; condition 2 - rays are adjusted by the collision with vehicle's own mesh, but not by the obstacles) separately, using PyVista's ray_trace, however, I struggle to put both of these together, so when you rotate the sensor (can be done with slider in the app), the rays are adjusted by the vehicle and the obstacle.

starts and ends are both arrays of points, which form a ray. clipped_ends/starts are then used to form the adjusted ray.

Couple things I tried, which imho had the highest potential - I attempted to merge both arrays together with `numpy.concatenate` , and comparing the length of both adjusted rays, so the code uses the shorter ray.

This is my first ever real project with pyhton, and I would be very glad for every piece of advice. Thanks in advance

```
[starts, ends] = rays
adjusted_starts = []
clipped_ends = []

for i in range len(starts)):
    raystart = starts[i]
    rayend = ennds[i]

  points, ind = vehicle.ray_trace(sensor_position, rayend, first_point=True)
    
  for obstacle in obstacles:
      points_obs, ind_obs= obstacle.ray_trace(raystart, rayend, first_point=True)
  if len(points) > 0:
    #loop replacing ray ends with points obtained by ray_trace
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and PyVista! ;) I'm afraid I don't understand your issue. Could you show more code about what you are doing? A [mcve] would be best, but your question is not strictly debugging so we could forgo that. But it's not clear to me what you're trying to do and exactly what you tried and didn't work. What are "the two conditions" you could "accomplish separately", and how are you trying to "put both of these together"?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I have edited the description and I hope that it is now a bit clearer :). I also added a bit more code - the app is quite complex and its a bunch of closely related code, so I hope this little addition helps as well

Answer (score 0):

OKey, for anyone, who would find this helpful, I managed to solve this at the end of the day:

**The correct approach is comparing the lenght of adjusted rays**. You have to be careful for empty return from `ray_trace`which indicated no intersection. I assigned variables `dis, dist_obs = 0, 0`and - dist_obs - legth of the ray colliding with an obstacle, dis - length of the ray colliding with the vehicle.

If your `ray_trace()`return is NOT empy - **Be careful for this step!!**: `points = points.astpye('float64')` - the same for  the `points_obs`, without that I got an error bcs of the non numeric type. Then, you can calculate the distances, I used `np.linalg.norm`.

If it IS empty, then set the distance `dist = np.infty`, the same for `dist_obs`.

Then you compare the `dist`and `dist_obs`and use the shorter one as a ray's endpoint

Hopefuly someone will find this helpful, if so, thanks for reading and good luck